# Telegram bot перезапускает python скрипт

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Есть бот, есть скрипт на питоне который выполняет какие-то расчеты, в конце формирует маленький отчет

Что нужно: чтобы при каждом обращении к боту ‘/start’ он заново перезапускал питоновский скрипт и тянул с него свежий отчет

Как такое реализовать?

```
import sys, os 
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."))
import telebot
import config
from report import stats #report это питоновский скрипт который нужно каждый раз выполнять при /start

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, stats)
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Нельзя ли запихнуть всю логику report.stats в функцию? Тогда можно было бы импортировать лишь однажды, а вызывать "скрипт" (теперь уже внешняя функция) каждый раз, когда это требуется.

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Генерирую отчёт, ожидайте..')
    stats()  # при условии, что это функция (def stats()) в файле report
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```